# Hyper V Networking - connect to local webserver VM

Tags: windows, iis, networking, hyper-v

I'm running windows 8 pro and have a VM running windows server 2008 for development purposes.

When I set up my VM to have external network access it is given a local network IP and I can connect to it from the host machine and all is well.

However when I am commuting I have no external network access and am unable to connect to the VM using my web browser.

Is it possible to set up some form of internal VM network which allows me to connect to the VM's without an external network connection?